List, up to isomorphism, all abelian groups of order at most 50, containing at least 3 elements of order 2 and at least 1 element of order 3.
I have this question I want to do. I think that I have a rough understanding in how to tackle it, but at some point I get lost.
My idea is sort of like this:
I first discard all orders which are not divisible by either 2 or 3. Then, I know I can use Sylow theory to weedle out any orders that have not at least two Sylow 2-groups and one Sylow 3-group. This is because any subgroup generated by an element of order 2 has only two elements of order 2, so if I guarantee that there exist two Sylow 2-groups in each order, I guarantee at least three (four) elements of order 2. The same with Sylow 3-groups.
This is where I run into a problem. I think it would be extremely cumbersome to manually check each order for at least two Sylow 2-groups and one Sylow 3-group.
After this step, I would use the Structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups to find all isomorphisms between the leftover orders.
Is there any other way to tackle this problem? Is my idea a valid way to do so? Any feedback is appreaciated.

"I can use Sylow theory to weedle out any orders that have not at least two Sylow 2-groups and one Sylow 3-group." The Sylow $p$- subgroups of an abelian group are always unique, because they are normal.

"any subgroup generated by an element of order 2 has only two elements of order 2, " A subgroup generated by one element of order two has one element of order $2$, not two.

This has several erroneous statements. It is unclear if this is due to you not saying what you mean, or of actual misconceptions.

You talk about groups having more than one Sylow $2$-subgroup. But these are abelian groups. In an abelian group, the Sylow $p$-subgroups are always unique, because they are necessarily normal. No abelian group can have more than one Sylow $2$-subgroup.

You say a subgroup generated by an element of order $2$ has "only two" elements of order $2$. In fact, it has one: if $x$ has order $2$, the subgroup it generates is $\{e,x\}$. Of these elements, $x$ has order $2$ and $e$ has order $1$.


You are correct that you need the group to have order divisible by $3$; that will guarantee at least one element of order $3$ (in fact, two: if $x$ has order $3$, then so does $x^{-1}$, and $x\neq x^{-1}$). You are also correct the group must have order divisible by $2$.
Rather than "more than one Sylow $2$-subgroup", which is impossible, what you need is for there to be more than one element of order $2$. Because if $x$ and $y$ are elements of order $2$, $x\neq y$, then $xy$ will also have order $2$ (it is not the identity, because $x\neq y$, and $(xy)^2 = x^2y^2=e$). That does not mean "more than one Sylow $2$-subgroup", however.
It does mean that whatever the Sylow $2$-subgroup is, it should not be cyclic: because a cyclic group of order $2^k$ has one and only one element of order $2$. So when you express this Sylow $2$-subgroup as a direct sum of cyclic subgroups of order a power of $2$, there need to be at least two summands. That means that the order must be divisible by at least $2^2$, and not merely $2$.
So now we know the order must be divisible by $12$; since it is also less than or equal to $50$, that only gives you possible order $12$, $24$, $36$, and $48$.
These orders factor as $12=2^2\times 3$; that tells you the structure of the $3$-part, and of the two possible structures for the $2$-part, only one is not cyclic. For $24=2^3\times 3$, you have only one possible $3$-part, and only one of the possible two structures for the $2$-part are not cyclic. Similar computations will work with $36=2^2\times 3^2$ (careful with the $3$-part here), and $48=2^4\times 3$.

Thank you for your response; these errors stem from misconceptions. Thank you for clarifying everything, it makes a lot of sense. I clearly did not think through it enough!

Say we have a finite group of order 2*3. Could I use Sylow theory to ensure the existence of an element of order 2? If I understand correctly, this should apply also to abelian groups. I know that there exists a Sylow 2-group, meaning that an element of order 2 exists, right?

@enfield That if the order of a group is divisible by $p$ then the group has an element of order $p$ is Cauchy's Theorem, which is usually used as part of any inductive argument in Sylow's.
